# Get rid of content ripping bots in a Rails 4 app served by Nginx using Passenger on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Our rails app is being inundated with requests from bots that are trolling using IP addresses. Every request results in an exception notification error message.

Our original Nginx server block:

```
server {
server_name example.com www.example.com *.example.com;
passenger_enabled on;
rails_env production;
root /home/deploy/cm/public;
passenger_app_root /home/deploy/cm;
passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
index index.html index.htm;

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
}

server {
if ($host = www.example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com *.example.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I placed 444.html file in the public directory and added this to the top of our Nginx server block:

```
server { 
listen 80; 
server_name _; 
return 444; 


}
```

This produced no change in the number of error messages. The error messages include this:

```
* SERVER_PORT                                 : 443
* SERVER_PROTOCOL                             : HTTP/1.1
* SERVER_SOFTWARE                             : nginx/1.18.0 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.6
```

How do I modify the server block to return a 444 if someone uses an IP address instead of our domain names?

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`.

Comment: Have you tried using the IP address as server name?  I never did that, but I've seen it around here a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your config:

```
server {
  listen       80  default_server;
  return 444;
}
```

Comment: This produced the same result.